# In T-SQL, is it possible for update statements to a parent table and a child table to deadlock?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If a SQL Server 2008r2 database were receiving update statements to both a child table, and also to the parent table (related by a Foreign Key constraint) at the same time, would the update statements be able to create a deadlock situation?

Note based on comments: The fields being updated in this situation are not the key fields, they are just counter fields.

Thanks.

Comment: No. Deadlock requires a shared dependency.

Comment: Yes I believe it could be possible if the values referenced by the foreign key constraint are themselves modified by the Update. Are they? I suggest sharing the table schema for your problem scenario for clarity.

Comment: @bnieland I would consider a PK FK relationship to be a shared dependency.

Comment: I've seen deadlocks where one of the queries was a *select*, and an FK is involved. Two updates seems like an easy one to achieve.

Comment: @Blam, you are, of course, correct, but the changing of a primary key is just a very very rare, especially if one uses synthetic keys.

Comment: Wrap it in a transaction and always update tables in the same order.  With todays computing speed if deadlock can happen then assume it will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can.  Here's proof:

```
--setup
use tempdb;
create table Parent (
    ParentID int not null, 
    constraint PK_Parent primary key clustered (ParentId)
);
insert into Parent values (1), (2), (3);
create table Child (
    ChildId int identity, 
    constraint PK_Child primary key clustered (ChildId),
    ParentId int, 
    constraint FK_Child_Parent foreign key (ParentId) 
        references Parent (ParentId)
);
insert into Child (ParentId) values (2), (2), (3);

--in window 1
use tempdb;
begin tran;
update Child set ParentId = 1 where ParentId = 3;


--in window 2
use tempdb;
begin tran;
update Parent set ParentId = 4 where ParentId = 1;

--back in window 1
update Child set ParentId = 4 where ParentId = 2;
```

I tested this and was able to produce a deadlock.

Comment: There were no such preclusions in the statement of the problem.  Pragmatism aside, this can happen.

Comment: True - it's just not very common

Comment: Nice answer.  Can it happen if you are updating fields that are not primary keys?

Comment: What is the purpose of a begin tran with a single statement?   +1

Comment: @Blam: W/o the explicit transaction, it's a race condition to create the deadlock.  Essentially, I'd have to submit the statement in window two at such a time as to have the first statement in window one done and the second not started.  I'm not that good.

Comment: @Sako73: That's a good question.  In the interest of teaching a man to fish, I suggest you give it a try by tweaking the example I've given here.  I have a gut feeling about what the answer is, but don't want to influence your experiment.